# Resize a picture to fit a JLabel in java

Tags: java, image, resize

I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't get any of the answers to work for me. 
here is the code produced by netbeans for my image:

```
jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pathtomastery/pathToMastery.png"))); // NOI18N
progressPanel.add(jLabel2);
jLabel2.setBounds(130, 20, 460, 80);
```

What can I add to this code to make my image resize to fit the size of the label?

Comment: Try my solution and let me know whether it works.

Comment: `but I can't get any of the answers to work for me` - well post links to the answers you tested. Why would they work for other people but not you. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). The image will automatically be scaled to fill the space available to the label.

Comment: Finally got this working! :) Thanks. This is the only method I managed to work with. It is very simple which it needs to be as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
jLabel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460, 80));
```

Comment: Setting the size of the label will not affect the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label with a new `icon` and use `BufferedImage` like:

```
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        bi.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
```